# Nginx: Ограничение доступа к картинке по кукам

Tags: nginx, cookie

Привет. Нужно в nginx запретить доступ к картинкам, если нет определенной куки.
Кусок кода

```
if ($cookie_mycookie != "1") {
    return 403;
}
```

работает в скопе `server { ... }` (ограничивается весь веб сайт), но не работает внутри `location /media/ { ... }`
Как можно сделать ограничение только для картинок?
Спасибо.

Comment: нужно бы посмотреть на конфиг. и на запрос. хотелось бы убедиться, что ваш запрос действительно обрабатывается в `location /media/ { ... } `

Comment: Да, забыл написать, что location обрабатывается. Там есть другие директивы и они работают. Игнорится только проверка кук. Это стандартный Nginx конфиг Magento 2

Comment: `if ($http_cookie !~ "mycookie=1")` тоже не работает?

Comment: С этим кодом Nginx даже не поднимается :-D

Comment: Весь конфиг и запрос в студию

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена. Условие правильное, но я в неправильном месте его использовал. Нужно было его поместить в location внутри другого location.